# G-WAN, output headers from CGI script

Tags: php, http, cgi, go, g-wan

I'm trying to set an HTTP header like `Content-Type` over a CGI script.

In `PHP`:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
// or
echo 'Content-Type: text/plain', "\r\n\r\n"; // as first line
```

or in `Go`:

```
fmt.Print("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n") // as first line
```

Both have no effect on the output.

How can this be done?

**EDIT**

I also tried the following in `Go`, using the `CGI` package:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "net/http/cgi"

func main() {
    r,e := cgi.Request()
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
        os.Exit(200)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", r)
    os.Exit(200)
}
```

but I get the error:

```
cgi: failed to parse REQUEST_URI into a URL:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

If your script returns a valid HTTP return code (like `200`) then G-WAN builds the corresponding HTTP Headers unless they are already there (starting with `"HTTP/1.x 200 OK"` here).

So, to force a given `content-type` with scripted languages *(other than those which support the G-WAN API like C, C++, D, and Objective-C)* you would have to `return 1` and define ALL the HTTP headers of your reply.

The programming languages that support the G-WAN API can use `get_env(argv, REPLY_MIME_TYPE);` (as shown in `fractal.c` and others) and let G-WAN build the rest of the headers.

**Question 2:**

The environment variable `REQUEST_URI` (while useful) is not part of the supported [CGI v1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) (RFC-3875). I have requested that `REQUEST_URI` is added in a future release.

The script examples provided with G-WAN list the supported variables by v3.12:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CGI/1.1 environment variables:
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// "AUTH_TYPE",          // "" | "Basic" | "Digest" | etc.
// "CONTENT_LENGTH",     // "" | entity_length
// "CONTENT_TYPE",       // "" | content_type
// "GATEWAY_INTERFACE",  // "CGI/1.1"
// "PATH_INFO",          // "" | ( "/" path )
// "PATH_TRANSLATED",    // disk filename for PATH_INFO
// "QUERY_STRING",       // "" | ?"hellox.c&name=toto"
// "REMOTE_ADDR",        // client IP address
// "REMOTE_HOST",        // client DNS name (or IP addr)
// "REMOTE_IDENT",       // client identity (RFC 1413), opt
// "REMOTE_USER",        // client identity (if auth)
// "REQUEST_METHOD",     // "GET" | "HEAD" | "PUT", etc.
// "SCRIPT_NAME",        // "" | ("/" path "hello.c")
// "SERVER_NAME",        // "gwan.com" | IP address
// "SERVER_PORT",        // "80"
// "SERVER_PROTOCOL",    // "HTTP/1.1" | "HTTP/1.0" | "HTTP/0.9"
// "SERVER_SOFTWARE",    // "G-WAN"
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that you can however access both the request and the parameters (if any) by using the following (and faster) Go code:

```
// args[1] /opt/gwan/10.10.20.80_80/#192.168.200.80/csp/hello.go
// args[2] arg1=123
// args[3] arg2=456

for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
   fmt.Printf("args[%d] %s<br>", i, os.Args[i])
 }
```

---

### UPDATE

We received this source code by email:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() 
{
   p := "<h1>Hello world!</h1><p>This is dog bla</p>"
   fmt.Printf("%s 200 OK\r\n", os.Getenv("SERVER_PROTOCOL"))
   fmt.Print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n")
   fmt.Print("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n")
   fmt.Printf("Content-Length: %d\r\n",len(p))
   fmt.Print("\r\n")
   fmt.Print(p)  
}
```

Please note that this code is incorrect: it does not even compile - and G-WAN reports the following errors:

```
loading.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: hell.go
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# command-line-arguments
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:7: syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline before {
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:9: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:10: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:11: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:12: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:13: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:14: non-declaration statement outside function body
0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/csp/hell.go:16: syntax error: unexpected }

 4|import "os"
 5|
 6|func main() 
 7!{
 8|   p := "<h1>Hello world!</h1><p>This is dog bla</p>"
 9|   fmt.Printf("%s 200 OK\r\n", os.Getenv("SERVER_PROTOCOL"))
10|   fmt.Print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n")
11|   fmt.Print("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n")


To run G-WAN, you must fix the error(s) or remove this Servlet.
```

This is most probably why you haven't seen the program being "updated": the old version, if any, was not replaced by the faulty version updated while G-WAN was running.

When you develop (editing scripts) you should always have a look at the terminal to check if your newly edited code compiles.

I recommend you to look at the (working) `hello.go` example to see what the requirements are for the expected definition of `main()` and the (madatory) `return code`.

When no return code is used (like in your code), G-WAN will inject default HTTP headers (`HTTP/0.9 200 OK` in your case) which will bypass your HTTP headers (if any) and as a result the Internet Browser will wait until it times-out because it does not know the length of your reply.

As documented in the examples and in the manual, to tell G-WAN not to create HTTP headers you have to return a value in the `1-99` range (`0 means close connection` and `200-600 is reserved for HTTP return codes` that tell G-WAN to generate the correspondig HTTP headers).

Comment: PS: Is it normal that I have to restart G-WAN for the changes in my Go scripts to take effect?

Comment: I just doubled-checked that with hello.go and I do not have this issue. Unlike Ruby or PHP, Go is a compiled language, which gives so more freedom. Drop us a line at G-WAN with an example that fails to refresh after an edition so we can investigate this further.

Comment: I have sent you a message through the contact form on gwan.com/about

Comment: No mail from Switzerland yesterday, not even in the logs. Use pierre@trustIeap.com

Comment: I have sent you an e-mail at that address. Thank you.

Comment: The source code that you have sent does not even compile, see the update in my reply above.