# How to set http response header when php is used with g-wan

Tags: php, http-headers, http-status-codes, g-wan

I add the header function in the hello.php sample, as below:

```
<?php
   header("xxxxx: yyyyy");
   fwrite(STDOUT, "see headers.<br><br>Hello, PHP!<br>current working directory: ".getcwd());
   exit(200); // return an HTTP code (200:'OK')
?>
```

but there is no such header found in firebug.
Who can explain how to add additional headers in php cli with gwan?

Comment: If you're running the CLI sapi, there there's no way to set headers - why on earther would anyone running a super-fast content server want to connect it up to PHP via the slowest possible interface?

Comment: if so, should i add headers by gwan's handler?

Comment: Really you should be using fastCGI - but IIRC there's not an officially supported plugin for the GWAN side (the joys of closed source development)

Comment: Gwan makes php fly. Gwan benchmarking showing php has the speed of about 600k req/s (in a xeon w3680 3.33GHz). Although it is slower than gwan with native c servlet, it is fast enough to meet my needs. With php, I can use gwan right now. But with c, i need time to learn.

Comment: From the G-WAN blog: "G-WAN is using PHP in the worse possible way (by invoking it as an extern process, and therefore not caching compiled code)"

Comment: thanks to symcbean. Will consider your findings. Will keep an eye on the cpu and memory usage.

Comment: Have you tried adding it in fwrite like fwrite(STDOUT, "xxxxx: yyyyy\r\n\r\nSee headers....")? In C G-WAN will not add headers if there's already a header on the reply.

Comment: See this almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357907/g-wan-output-headers-from-cgi-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gil and Richard,
Now, it is what i did according to your advices. PHP works in gwan with customized headers.

```
<?php
 $output='See headers....Hello, PHP!<br>from gwan';
   $len=strlen($output);
   fwrite(STDOUT, "HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: $len\r\nxxxxx: yyyyy\r\n\r\n$output");
    exit(1);
?>
```

i use `ab -c 1000 -n 100000 http:127.0.0.1/?hello.php`
The memory usage is increased by **0.7% of 2.9GiB = 0.0203GiB**
The CPU usage is increased from **20% to 75% = 50%** (ab run in the same machine with gwan)
I did it in my old machine intel P9300 2.26GHz x 2, ubuntu 12.04

it finished in 9.543 sec without failure
about **10,479** req/sec

Comment: For an **Intel Core2 Duo P9300 @ 2.26GHz [passmark score: 1509]**: http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core2+Duo+P9300+%40+2.26GHz,  this is not bad (recent CPUs are 10x more powerful). Note that this PHP script will run much faster if you let G-WAN generate the HTTP headers by using exit(200); instead of exit(1);

Answer (score 0):

Tom is right. To bypass the HTTP headers injected by G-WAN (because you `returned 200`) you should return a value in the 1-99 range (an invalid HTTP status code).

Then, you own HTTP headers (if any) will be used.

`return 0;` means close connection and `return 200-600;` is reserved for HTTP return codes that tell G-WAN to generate the correspondig HTTP headers.

The PDF manual is a resource worth reading.

---

Just a word about `"fastCGI"`: it will NEVER be faster than running scripts in parallel from several threads... *without* ever involving the network (between the server and PHP).

The more intermediate layers or interfaces you add, the slower things will be so as `"fastCGI"` runs scripts via an interface using the network is necessarily *slower* than running the code directly (and I am not even addressing the fact that the PHP "fastCGI" server is very slow, that the fastCGI protocol iself is pointlessly complex and therefore slow, and that, on the top of that, the fasctCGI implementation is more than sub-optimal).

Now we have multicore CPUs, parallelism does not necessarily involve HORIZONTAL scalability (the scalability obtained by running code on many connected machines).

It is way cheaper (faster and more energy efficient) to scale VERTICALLY (on the many CPU Cores that reside on the local machine).

As the number of CPU Cores is growing exponentially, there is no way back: scaling VERTICALLY will make more and more sense as time goes.